# Given two variables, test if another variable is between them

Tags: java, variables, numbers

I would like to test whether a variable is between two other variables, if this is unclear look at my code. This code works, I am just looking for a shorter and more efficient way of performing the same thing.

```
public boolean isBetween(double test, double n1, double n2){
        double lowN = n1 < n2 ? n1 : n2;
        double highN = n1 > n2 ? n1 : n2;
        if(n1 == n2 && test == n1){
            return true;
        }
        if(test >= lowN && test <= highN){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Currently, I use two ternary operators to define which variable is lower and which is higher and then I see whether the test variable is between them

Comment: `return test >= Math.min(n1, n2) && test <= Math.max(n1, n2);`

Comment: Having said that, this is off-topic.  It belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com - and that's why I didn't submit an answer.

Comment: Here's a more elegant and more intuitive solution (if you don't want to use `Math.min` and `Math.max`). - `return test >= n1 && test <= n2 || test >= n2 && test <= n1;`

Comment: Dawood ibn Kareem, I wish I could plus one a comment, thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Math.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-double-double-) and [`Math.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-double-double-):

```
private static boolean isBetween(double test, double d1, double d2) {
    return test >= Math.min(d1, d2) && test <= Math.max(d1, d2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
public boolean isBetween(double test, double n1, double n2) {
    return n1 > test ? n2 > test && n2 < n1 : n2 > n1 && n2 < test;
}
```

that said I actually like the other solution more personally, more readable; referring to the use of Math.min() and Math.max()

Answer (score 1):

This part is not even needed. It should work without it also.

```
    if(n1 == n2 && test == n1){
        return true;
    }
```

Also using Math.min() and Math.max() is essentially giving same efficiency as your code. You can use them if you want to make your code short or look more readable.